# Pinterest API : Authentication not working : 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: javascript, api, pinterest

I am trying to make your javascript API work. I followed the basic setup on your js api docs. But I am getting a `401 unauthorized`. I am not finding any solution how to resolve this.

I added `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` to my php code but it does not work.

Any suggestions what to do ? Thanks for authenticating. Getting your information...

> pinteresturl/v1/me/:1 GET pinteresturl/v1/ 401 (Unauthorized)
>   (index):1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.pinterest.com/v1/me/.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://www.svenfraeys.com'; is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 401. sdk.js:1 The request
>   did not complete because of a failure on the network level.